# Can't connect after changing MySQL root password in WAMP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This is one of the most common problems found with WAMPSERVER.  I ran through this problem too and posted my solution under the same title here . But after getting no appropriate reply/solution I had to dump Wampserver and install XAMPP instead . It works smoothly (For  solution to the problem `Scroll down`  and look under UPDATE section or you can read what my problem was exactly before you run into a quicky )

Here are the details :

Okay ,I am using WAMP  and changed mysql password from phpMyAdmin interface of all the root accounts.
Now after that i when i tried to access localhost/phpmyadmin - The access was denied and the interface is not ready to show up .
Here is the Error

> #2000 - mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command `SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password')`. This will store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag from your my.cnf file.
> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Then afterwards i tried using the method given in Reference manual for resetting the password by creating that init.txt file (Hope you all know what i am reffering to here . If not just try this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-windows))

Then following all the instructions clearly the CMD in its output shows some following negative statements:

> Invalid password found for "Edited_root_username" @localhost

Note: the rootusername that CMD shows is the one that i changed through phpMyAdmin interface. the previous one was of course - root.

And some other catching statement in cmd was:

> please check yor mysql manual for correct syntax near  `FLUSH PRIVELEGES.

Can't figure out where the problem is ???

**[Update]**

Okay , the problem will not be solved until you reintsall the WAMPSERVER . But  if you want to change your ROOT password for the new installation by following the instructions given in the mysql manual , Please don't bother .It is a total waste of time  . After following the procedure in mysql manual  there are same errors in command prompt as i mentioned above . Yes , this time you do have access to PHPMYADMIN (due to reinstallation) but as soon you execute the mysql init.txt file , PHPMYADMIN  says `you have no database privileges` (seems WAMP is not ready to give  up--anyways screw this and have a look at solution below)

**`Solution:`**

Back up the data you have under mysql->data folder and Instead of reinstalling Wamp **install XAMPP** .
The procedure laid down in XAMPP password change help page for changing root password  really works like a charm (check the FaQ link  for  quick access ->to this question).

And yes place the earlier  data you copied  from mysql->data folder in WAMP in the same folder DATA folder under mysql in your new XAMPP Installation .

IT WORKED FOR ME and I am having access to almost all databases i created earlier in wamp

NOTE---`Some of the tables might not show up if their .FRM files are not having corresponding` .MYD`and`.MYI `extension files  .But important ones did showed up for me :)`.

Comment: Apparently you updated the root password while not using the PASSWORD() function which hashes the password (basically encrypts the password in a way which cannot be decrypted), can you access the database using: mysqladmin from the database machine? here's how to reset the password: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: I already shared the same link in my post . Can you please read the post carefully !

Comment: And what "mysqladmin" you talking about . Hope u mean PHPMYADMIN !!

Comment: a) the links are not the same, you gave a link to version 5.5 but you error message indicates you are running version 4.1 (that was my link), please carefully notice the links.
b) I'm not talking about PHPMYADMIN but a command line utility called mysqladmin or mysql (assuming you are running this on a linux machine which you have failed to mention).

Comment: Again , read the error carefully please . It says 4.1+ and not only 4.1 . Anyways you  are clear on the Mysql version i am running i.e 5.5.8 and i am using it  on Windows .  I do have mysql console (command line utility for WAMP) which asks me for password on the very front .  And i have which  tried entering new password as well as old one and even tried with empty password .BUt the console shuts as soon as it could. So the short answer to your question will be NO Any further info will be appreciated .

Comment: Ok, so now that we have the versions & links synchronized, did you follow the init file instructions?

Comment: @yaniro..Yes, exactly did as mentioned. And cmd prompt on executing the file  says for every root user(3 in my case)
: `Invalid password found for "root" @localhost`
 and similar two other statements.

Comment: please see my solution here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010268/phpmyadmin-doesnt-connect-after-root-password-change/20819668#20819668

Answer (score 5):

Open a MySQL console (taskbar > wamp > MySQL > MySQL console )

type: `SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_current_password')`