# Back up MYSQL data after loosing access to PHPMYADMIN interface

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-backup

I just want to know how to back up data From MYSQL database and Still be able to use that data 
again on reinstalling MYSQL ?

NOTE-- i got into this problem after changing my ROOT password . I posted a question regarding fixing this .But unfortunately don't got the solution .So i decided the last step will be to BACK UP my data !
  Here is a LINK to that
 post

[Can't connect after changing MySQL root password in WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635071/cant-connect-after-changing-mysql-root-password-in-wamp)

P.S----I HAVE **NO ACCESS TO PHPMYADMIN**

Comment: Do you have access (e.g. with `ssh`, or to a physical or virtual terminal) to the machine, or to the MySQL internal files ? Can you shutdown the MySQL server (e.g. run `/etc/init.d/mysql stop`) ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch...I  am working on a locahost. I have access to all the data .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to your wamp installation drive, and then go to wamp folder
traverse it if the drive is `C:` and installation folder is `WAMP`
`C:\wamp\mysql\data\`
you will see the folder as the name of your database here
copy it to other place and paste it after reinstall phpmyadmin in the same position

Comment: @hemant...are you sure it will work without any problems . Sorry even for asking such a question but i am a little worried about my data ?

Comment: ya it will work surely, but if you are in trouble then make sure it yourself first my using this things in other system (copy and paste your data in other system)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, assuming that you know the new/old/current root passwords run the following

```
mysqldump -u root --all-databases -p
```

This should ask you the password and dump sql onto the stdout.

To save it to backup.sql,

```
 mysqldump -u root --all-databases -p > backup.sql
```

Comment: @pdvyas....Where i am supposed to run this command ? Mysql console too asks for a password.

Comment: exactly -p means, it'll ask for password. Did you try all the ones you know?

Comment: Yes. And if mysql / mysqldump is not in your PATH, then cd (change directory) to the bin of mysql and then run from there.